# How to use replace in openquery SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, openquery

I need to remove Special characters from columns which has them from linked server using OpenQuery.

Here is the example, but it's not working

```
DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Query =
'

      UPDATE OPENQUERY
      (
            LINKEDSERVER, 
            ''SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE NAME Like ''''' + '%###%' +  '''''''
      )
      SET NAME = REPLACE(NAME, ''###'', '''')

'

EXEC (@Query)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question does not seem to match the code you're trying to use. Are the columns you're trying to clense of values in a table on a linked sever?

Then maybe this is what your looking for:

```
UPDATE OPENQUERY (LINKEDSERVER, 'SELECT name FROM Table WHERE name like ''%###%'' ') 
SET name = REPLACE(NAME, '###', '');
```